# Analyze the progression and mark the harmonic rhythm using ( S W s w )

Tags: rhythm

[image]

basically this question requires me to mark the harmonic ryhtymn using
taking it as 2 beats per chord

S very strong s strong W weak w very weak

Ab7 F7|Bb7 Eb7 | F-7 c-7| Dbmaj7 F7|

S W| s w| S W | s w |

Bb-7 C-7|Dbmaj7 G7|C7 F7| Bb7 Eb7|

S W| s w| W w | s w |

did I marked it correctly that is what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: Need to refer to teacher with this. Too vague.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such an assignment in my life. What class is this? Is there meant to be a correct answer?

The notion of a "weak" or "strong" chord is highly subjective, and to the extent that we can talk about weak or strong pulses in the harmonic rhythm, they must depend on the phrasing of the melody, no?

For all I know, those eight measures could consist of one 3-bar phrase followed by one 5-bar phrase, in which case I guess the `Dbmaj7` would probably be `S` instead of `s`.
That's not to say that you're wrong—just that the parameters of the assignment are too vague for anyone to claim one answer is the most correct.

But knowing nothing else, if it were me, I would assume four-bar phrasing and put `S w` in the first measure and `s w` in all the others.

Comment: if its 2 beat per bar then how will it be ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for a class assignment or an exercise in a book. But the question mixes up metrical accent about strong/weak beats with harmonic rhythm which is more about proportions and phrasing. It isn't clear if *you* are mixing up the terminology or the assignment does, because you only include an image of the staff without the question wording from the source. If you quote some of the assignment text, it might become clearer what is going on. But, I'll try to answer with standard theory ideas.

In your example the harmonic rhythm would be described as two chords per bar, assuming 4/4 time, two beats per chord. In terms of metrical accent the normal beat accents in 4/4 would be `S w W w`. So, if the example intends the chords to placed on beats 1 and 3, the accents on the chords will be strong S for the first chord on beat 1 and medium weak W for the second chord on beat 3.

Importantly, those patterns `S w W w` for the meter and `S _ W _` for the harmonic rhythm are only the *conceptual* definition of the meter and that conception is maintain for *all measures*. The thing you are doing in your suggested answer `...S W| s w| W w | s w |` seems more like dynamic markings for *specific performance dynamics*, an indication of exactly how you would perform the dynamics. But meter and harmonic rhythm don't have anything to do with actual performance dynamics.

It might help you to think about it in comparison to *rhyme scheme* and *metrical foot* in poetry. Those two things are conceptual only `AABB` shows where rhymes are placed conceptually, but it doesn't tell you the actual syllables rhymed. Metrical foot will tell you where accents are placed conceptually, but a reader doesn't necessarily recite the poem with that accenting. The strength of their voice may rise and fall over lines and stanzas.

Harmonic rhythm and metrical accent in music are similarly conceptual. They are more about structure than performance.